# como puedo mostrar los cumpleaños de las personas todos los años?

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

```
 renderBirthday() {
      this.persons.forEach(function (data) {
      const render = {
        className: 'birthday',
        event_id: data.id,
        title: data.name + '  ' + data.last_name + '   ' ,
        start: data.birth,
        textColor: 'black',
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      };
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', render, true );
    })
  },
```

tengo que mostrar los cumpleaños de las personas pero solo aparecen en la fecha que los he creado.

Comment: Fullcalendar no soporta eventos recurrentes (solo para semanales). Te fijaste en alguna opcion pura para VUE? mira este hilo: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/387

Comment: gracias por el aporte, eso estoy viendo o por lo menos poder mostrar los cumpleaños en el año actual

Comment: Yo usaria alguno de los montones de controles puros de VUE para esto, asi ademas no tenes que lidiar con renders ni con js...

Comment: disculpa y cuales son esos controles?

Comment: que te diviertas! https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#calendar